# How can I exclude a pattern from tagcloud facet in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using Elasticsearch for generating the tag cloud in our site. The query used to create the tag cloud is as following.

```
{
"size": 0,
"facets": {
    "tagcloud": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "body.body",
            "size": "20",
            "exclude": [
                "http",
                "t.co"
            ]
        }
    }
},
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "body.postedTime": {
                        "gte": "2015-08-26T00:00:00Z",
                        "lte": "2015-08-26T23:59:59Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

The exclude section works fine. What I need is to exclude some patterns like excluding all links.

Is that possible in elasticsearch ? if yest, how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Terms aggregation has exclude pattern option too. 
Check it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values).
So , just use "http.*" as exclude pattern.

For this to work , you need to enable [UAX Email tokeznier](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html) , so that the links wont get tokenized whle analysis.